# How to make Java regex to replace non-alphabetic signs and add underscores in Java class names?

Tags: java, regex, replace, non-alphanumeric

I am generating Java classes from input which represents some model language.
Customer who creates input models, doesn´t care about Java, so sometimes I get this kind of names of classes:

1) Struct+ 
2) Controller: 
3) *

Obviously, this is not compilable.
I would need some nice regex for this to generate something like this:

1) Struct_more
2) Controller_prefix
3) All

Could you please help me to sort out regex for this input?

I want to underscore in between and replace non-alphabetic signs with something meaningfull and valid. Thanks

Comment: You can not do that with only one regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well a regex obviously can't replace something on its own. You'd need something to match the regex-meaning with a descriptive string. But a simple regex to match any non alphanumerical character would be somthing like this:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9]
```

Comment: I guess, I could start with something like this:
`String className = "Struct+";
String pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9]";
System.out.println(className.replaceAll(pattern, "_nonalpha"));`

Comment: Sure, that would make them valid class-names. But it would not really be descriptive of what the original regex operator was. For example "Struct+" would give you "Struct_nonalpha"
"Struct*" would give you the same, if thats not a problem, you have found an easy solution ;)

Comment: Yes, I agree with you about the limits. I will talk to customer about this and try to enhance it eventually. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: You could also check for every possible operator you expect to find. So you might have `className.replaceAll("\\*", "_all")` to replace all asterisks with "_all". ("\\" to escape the * and not interpret it as regex). You would have to do this for every character though.

Comment: That´s true, I will try it. 
So far, I´ve found only those three, +, : and *

Comment: You could maybe mix the two. Replace all known ones with their according string representation and everything else with generic "_nonalpha". You'll have to see. Good luck ;)